# Custom NavigationView Icons

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, navigationview

I want to make custom colored Icons for NavigationView Items.
I added some code from old post as following.

```
       <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Main"  helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MainPage"   >
            <winui:NavigationViewItem.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    
                    <Image Source="/Assets/Icons/HomeIcon.png" Width="25" Height="25"/>
                    
                </StackPanel>
            </winui:NavigationViewItem.Content>
        </winui:NavigationViewItem>
```

The Change is OK in designer as The following Image .
[image]

But during execution, Nothing happned as in the following Image:
[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Please check if the `build action` of file icon is `Content`.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT
the Image file  build action is Content by default

Comment: Ok, I try above code,  but I can't reproduce your problem, please try to clean your solution or provide [mcve].

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT
The project is just 4 blank pages with navigationview using Windows template studio.
Nothing Modified, Just these two lines!!!!

Comment: Yep,  I make the project with Windows template studio. but I can't repro this problem, Please try to clean your solution. or make a new blank app for testing again

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT hello Master.
I made it , Starting from a blank Project , and add Navigationview, Not using Windows Template Studio, it worked that way, but why ?? Not figured it

Comment: It's hard to say, may be debug issue. if you have solved the problem, please feel free post your answer and  mark yourself.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT
Sure, Many thanks

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT,
Please Check it below,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But during execution, Nothing happned as in the following Image:

During the testing, you code is correct, and add image into `NavigationViewItem` is general way to custom navigation item icon. we have made sample, and it work as expect. It looks your project has debug problem. please try to clean your project or make a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by removing the x:Uid From the menu Item AS shown below:

```
<winui:NavigationViewItem helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MainPage" >
     <winui:NavigationViewItem.Content>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
             <Image Source="/Assets/Icons/HomeIcon.png" Width="45" Height="45" >
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <TextBlock x:Uid="Shell_Main" Text="temp"/>
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        </Image>
           </StackPanel>
     </winui:NavigationViewItem.Content>
                
  </winui:NavigationViewItem>


  <winui:NavigationViewItem   helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:ExcelToolsPage">
       <winui:NavigationViewItem.Content>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
              <Image Source="/Assets/Icons/HomeIcon.png" Width="45" Height="45" >
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <TextBlock x:Uid="Shell_ExcelTools" Text="temp"/>
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        </Image>
           </StackPanel>
      </winui:NavigationViewItem.Content>
 </winui:NavigationViewItem>
```

[image: The Navigation View]

The problem Now is Make these Icons distributed along the whole pan vertically.

Comment: I appreciate you sharing your solution with the community. The last line in this should probably be introduced as a _new_ question.

Comment: @JeremyCaney
thanks for your comment, the Last line not a question, but the problem I wanted to solve, and already solved, I will share it once tested .